# how can I stop top-panel from overlapping window border in dualscreen mode?

Tags: gnome-panel, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I have a dual-screen setup with mu laptop screen as primary and my LCD screen as secondary placed over the laptop screen. 
On my laptop screen I have a top-panel at the top of the screen and docky at the bottom. 
When the LCD screen is off/disconnected, there is no problem when maximizing the window on the laptop screen, but when it is on, the top-window border gets hidden behind my top-panel. 
How can I get it to only maximize to the panel and not below it? it is quite annoying that I cannot get to the min/maximize/close window buttons etc.

Comment: OK I need this answered too - and moving the panel or deleting it or auto-hiding it is NOT an answer.  The top screen in my case is a 40" TV on a wall, and I don't want to have to crane my neck every time I want to adjust the volume.  Why is it so hard to make the stupid panel stay behind the windows?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same physical monitor setup and the same annoying problem!

I kind of solved this by dragging the top-panel to the top of the LCD screen.

***BUT*** to be able to move the top-panel up to the top of the LCD screen you first need to untick the "Expand" checkbox in the panels properties (right-click on the panel to get to them).

Then you can grag & drop the panel upto the top of your LCD screen and when its docked there, it won't overlap over your normal apps windows.